# How many questions are submitted on the stackexchenge network in one second?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, statistics

How many questions are submitted on the stackexchenge network in one second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [API](http://stackapps.com) — `questions_per_minute` data — it's `3.86` questions per minute, so `0.06433333333333333` questions in one second.

```
stackoverflow.com 3.08
serverfault.com 0.11
meta.stackoverflow.com 0.03
superuser.com 0.13
stackapps.com 0.0
webapps.stackexchange.com 0.01
gaming.stackexchange.com 0.02
webmasters.stackexchange.com 0.02
cooking.stackexchange.com 0.0
gamedev.stackexchange.com 0.01
photo.stackexchange.com 0.01
stats.stackexchange.com 0.01
math.stackexchange.com 0.05
diy.stackexchange.com 0.01
gis.stackexchange.com 0.01
tex.stackexchange.com 0.02
askubuntu.com 0.11
money.stackexchange.com 0.0
english.stackexchange.com 0.02
ux.stackexchange.com 0.01
unix.stackexchange.com 0.02
wordpress.stackexchange.com 0.02
cstheory.stackexchange.com 0.01
apple.stackexchange.com 0.02
rpg.stackexchange.com 0.0
bicycles.stackexchange.com 0.0
programmers.stackexchange.com 0.04
android.stackexchange.com 0.01
answers.onstartups.com error
electronics.stackexchange.com 0.01
boardgames.stackexchange.com 0.0
physics.stackexchange.com 0.01
homebrew.stackexchange.com 0.0
sharepoint.stackexchange.com 0.02
security.stackexchange.com 0.0
writers.stackexchange.com 0.0
audio.stackexchange.com 0.0
dba.stackexchange.com 0.01
graphicdesign.stackexchange.com 0.0
scifi.stackexchange.com 0.01
guitars.stackexchange.com 0.0
codereview.stackexchange.com 0.0
codegolf.stackexchange.com 0.0
quant.stackexchange.com 0.0
pm.stackexchange.com 0.0
skeptics.stackexchange.com 0.01
fitness.stackexchange.com 0.0
drupal.stackexchange.com 0.01
mechanics.stackexchange.com 0.0
parenting.stackexchange.com 0.0
49 sites 3.86 total questions per minute
```

**Note**: I don't see an API on answers.onstartups.com, so it is not included in the calculation, also Area51 is not included.

Comment: Rounding errors bewaaaaaaaare (guessing many of those 0.01's are rounded up), but yeah this is a cool way to get a general feel for how many there are

Comment: Is there a link to the API page to see how this number has changed?